# GCM TOKEN REGISTRATION ON ANDROID 2.3

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

I tried to implement the new Google Cloud Messaging API on an Application i'm working on, it works fine on version 4.2++, i can receive notifications and act on it. But there is a serious issue i experience in version 2.3. or lower versions:

```
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    System.out.println("STARTING SERVICE !!!!! ");
    InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
    try {
        final String token = instanceID.getToken(getString(R.string.sender_id), GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
        System.out.println("GCM TOKEN :::: " + token);
        if(!token.isEmpty()) {
            new MyGcmRunner(token, this);
        }
    }
    catch (IOException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    //instanceID.getToken()
}
```

with the above implementation i receive a GCM TOKEN. The first time i try to send a message to GCM server using this token it returns a successful message, even though the client app doesn't receive any notification.

If i try again it returns the below error:

`{"multicast_id":5130293481949972794,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"NotRegistered"}`]}

I really don't understand why it behaves like this, is there something i'm missing.

**NOTE** : The situation occurs in android version 2.3 or lower versions that i'm currently experimenting on.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<permission
    android:name="com.healthboxes.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.healthboxes.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/hb_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name=".Authentication.Services.HBInstanceIDListenerService"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name=".Authentication.Services.RegistrationService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" />
    <service
        android:name=".General.Service.GcmMessageListenerService"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <activity
        android:name=".HBSplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_hbsplash"
        android:noHistory="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Authentication.Activity.HBLoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_hblogin"
        android:parentActivityName=".HBSplashActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.healthboxes.app.HBSplashActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Home.Activity.HBHomeActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_hbhome"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:parentActivityName=".Authentication.Activity.HBLoginActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.healthboxes.app.Authentication.Activity.HBLoginActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".HBAppointment.Activity.HBCreateAppointmentActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_create_appointment"
        android:parentActivityName=".Home.Activity.HBHomeActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.healthboxes.app.Home.Activity.HBHomeActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".HBRiskChecker.Activity.HBQuestionActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_hbquestion"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:parentActivityName=".Home.Activity.HBHomeActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.healthboxes.app.Home.Activity.HBHomeActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Authentication.Activity.SignUpActivity"
        android:label=""
        android:parentActivityName=".Authentication.Activity.HBLoginActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.healthboxes.app.Authentication.Activity.HBLoginActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Authentication.Activity.HBSignUpProcessActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_hbsign_up_process"
        android:parentActivityName=".Authentication.Activity.SignUpActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.healthboxes.app.Authentication.Activity.SignUpActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activity.HBDetailActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_detail"
        android:parentActivityName=".Home.Activity.HBHomeActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.healthboxes.app.Home.Activity.HBHomeActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Chat.Activity.HBChatActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_hbchat"
        android:parentActivityName=".Home.Activity.HBHomeActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.healthboxes.app.Home.Activity.HBHomeActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activity.SearchActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_search"
        android:parentActivityName=".Home.Activity.HBHomeActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.healthboxes.app.Home.Activity.HBHomeActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activity.ProfileActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_profile"
        android:parentActivityName=".Activity.SearchActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.healthboxes.app.Activity.SearchActivity" />
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".Chat.Activity.ChatRequestActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_chat_request"
        android:exported="true"
        android:parentActivityName=".Home.Activity.HBHomeActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="CHAT_ACTIVITY" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.healthboxes.app.Home.Activity.HBHomeActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Post here your manifest

Comment: @Fondesa see edit for manifest

Comment: This is a compatibility issue. Instance ID has Google Play Service dependency which needs Android 2.3 or higher. See here: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup.

Comment: @KayAnn thanks, but to be honest, GCM is a piss of sh*t... its really annoying, my messages aren't delivered when device is turned back on, if i shut down the app and re-launch same issue. What better push notification can i use as gcm isn't reliable, infact gcm isn't a PUSH SERVICE.. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can have added these two permissions for GCM:

```
<permission
    android:name="com.healthboxes.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.healthboxes.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

Try to add also:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

Comment: Still the same issue... the problem is that i receive the token quite alright, but after the 2nd time of sending a notification to the device with the token received, it returns an error that token isn't registered whereas a token had initially been received. How long does it take a device to get Registered in google cloud server

Comment: Ok I get your frustration, but tbh I think you are not storing the token properly which is a part of app server side implementation. You can verify that and if you think this makes sense then post some serverside code and add relevant tags and you might just get this going good.